# Parse Server Aggregate Query Results - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, aggregate, parse-server

I have been looking for an aggregate function for ParseQuery but haven't been able to find it. Do you know if this is possible for Android (Java)? Can you point me to the related documentation if there is any?

Thanks